# WCF windows form not working in .exe but working in visual studio

Tags: c#, forms, wcf, server, client

I will appreciate if you have any idea for my issue.

Followed MS WCF direction to create a client server console app and working fine running as administrator at DOS prompt.  Then I changed the console app to windows forms but it won't run as administrator at file explorer (can't find the service).  But if I run the server form at Visual Studio, then I can run client form at file explorer (no need to be administrator).  If I run the server form at file explorer, I can run client form at Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

After you host the wcf service in the application, you can find the bin in your project folder and then find the shortcut of your compiled program in this directory, so that the wcf service can be hosted in this process and not Occupy visual studio. Then run your client program in vs to call the wcf service. Compile the program which host the WCF service, and the folder where the shortcut is located will be displayed after success.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Basically I looking for an easy way to do a client server app.  It looks like there is a lot more setup for remote client.  I will research more.  Thanks!